# Split a list in python into different text files

Tags: python

I want to write three separate text files for each three element of the list below:

```
my_list = ['text1', 'text1', 'text1', 'text2', 'text2', 'text2', 'text3', 'text3', 'text3']
result = [my_list[idx:idx + 3] for idx in range(0, len(my_list), 3)]
outfiles = ['file1', 'file2', 'file3']
for f in outfiles:
    with open ('{}.txt'.format(f),'w') as fo:
        for x in result:
            for y in x:
                fo.write(str(y) + '\n')
```

Please help me correcting the code above.

file1 should consist:

```
text1
text1
text1
```

file2:

```
text2
text2
text2
```

file3:

```
text3
text3
text3
```

But my code above writes:

```
text1
text1
text1
text2
text2
text2
text3
text3
text3
```

Comment: What you would like to write in the files? The words separated by commas, spaces or the words as a list?

Comment: But _why_?  Is it because the strings are all the same string?  Or is it because you want to split the list into 3 evenly sized chunks?  The answer to _that_ dramatically changes the solution... e.g. what do you want if `my_list` is `['text1', 'text1', 'text2']`?  or `['text1', 'text1', 'text2', 'text3']` or simply `['text1']` for that matter...

Comment: @mgilson i have edited the question, please have a look

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this using a loop to iterate over a slice of the list. Here, we are using the variable `i` to indicate which slice of the list will be used in each iteration:

```
my_list = ['text1', 'text1', 'text1', 'text2', 'text2', 'text2', 'text3', 'text3', 'text3']
outfiles = ['file1', 'file2', 'file3']

i = 0 # to keep count of which words will be written
for f in outfiles:
    with open ('{}.txt'.format(f), 'w') as fo:
        for word in my_list[i:i + 3]:
            fo.write(word + "\n")
    i += 3
```

Comment: your code is interesting. btw what's the meaning of i += 3

Comment: It's equivalent to `i = i + 3`. It's just a short-cut.

Comment: thanks, but i could not shed light into my mind how your code works from the beginning.

Comment: @julie First loop through the names of the files you want to write. Then open (create) the file to write in it. Then loop through the words and write each. If you don't get what `my_list[i:i+3]` do, just use a `print` to see what is happening.

Comment: first part i could understand, but after i=0 i could not understand how you loop through the words and write each

Comment: In first iteration, `i` is 0, so `my_list[0:3]` is `['text1','text1','text1']`. You will loop through that list, and each iteration you will write the respective word. Next, `i` is 3, so `my_list[3:6]` is `['text2','text2','text2']`, and do the same...

Comment: Increase `i` in 3 each iteration: `[0, 3, 6...]`. Why 3? Because that's the number of words you want in each file.

Answer (score 0):

I would probably use `itertools.groupby` here ...

```
for i, (k, group) in enumerate(groupby(my_list), 1):
    with open('file{}.txt'.format(i), 'w') as fout:
        fout.writelines(item + '\n' for item in group)
        # fout.write('\n'.join(group))  # another alternative which doesn't write a newline at the end of the file.
```

This assumes that the initial list was sorted and it seems a little silly to write the same thing to a file over and over, but if you really have a more diverse list, you can always sort and group by the result of some key function which would be applied to each element in the list...

Comment: `itertools` _is_ a common python tool.

Answer (score 0):

```
outfiles = ['file1', 'file2', 'file3']
my_list = ['text1', 'text1', 'text1', 'text2', 'text2', 'text2', 'text3', 'text3', 'text3']
for i in range(0, len(my_list), len(outfiles)):
    with open(my_list, 'a') as outfile:
        for line in outfiles[i:i+len(my_list)]:
            outfile.write(line)
            outfile.write('\n')
```

The following can be done with minimal edits to your code:

```
outfiles = ['file1', 'file2', 'file3']
my_list = ['text1', 'text1', 'text1', 'text2', 'text2', 'text2', 'text3', 'text3', 'text3']

round = 0
i = 0
while len(files)*round + i < len(my_list):
    for i,outfilepath in enumerate(outfiles):
        with open(outfilepath) as outfile:
            outfile.write(my_list[len(files)*round + i])
    i += 1
```

Comment: @julie: I don't understand what the code is attempting to do. Could you please post the desired output in each of the files after the code runs?

Comment: @inspectorG4dget in line `for i in range(0, len(my_list), len(outfiles):` one `)` is missing

Comment: @m.wasowski: good catch. Thanks for the bug report. It's fixed now